# CKEditor Classic editor with simpleUpload not formatting image correctly with <img tag (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, file-upload, ckeditor5

I'm using the simpleUpload plugin with ckeditor 5 to insert an image into a textarea.

```
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#fulleditor'), {
    simpleUpload: {
        // The URL that the images are uploaded to.
        uploadUrl: '{{route('ckeditor.image_upload.news', ['id' => $article->id])}}',
        headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
            }
    }
});
```

The function at the route is then uploading the image and returning

```
return response()->json(['url' => 'http://laravel.test/storage/78969/testimage.jpeg']);
```

Instead of then creating

```
<img src="http://laravel.test/storage/78969/testimage.jpeg" />
```

or similar, I'm getting:

```
![](http://laravel.test/storage/78969/testimage.jpeg)
```

When I save the document it saves like that in the DB.

Should I be encoding somehow or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance